# showing 2nd page in a table in a primary content div in php

Tags: php

I have a php form that once a user hits the SAVE button, it takes them to another page called: ADVISORSEDITPOST.php, What I need is to have that page opened up in the main pages primary content container which is shown below.

I got it to show up in the page but with this part of the code
("Location: /PHP1_CombsW/index.php?menukey=10");
The data shows up on another webpage filled out (great!)but not on the main page (not so great!)
but with this code
header("Location: /PHP1_CombsW/index.php?menukey=10");
The page shows up in the main page where I want it but i get no information back from the web form .

The below code is my main page and snippet on the top is from the submitted form --latest attempt.

Please help.

thank you

code

```
<?php
    switch($_POST['action']) { 
    case "Cancel": 
        header("Location: Index.php");
        break; 
    case "Save":
    ("Location: /PHP1_CombsW/index.php?menukey=10");
        $AdvisorID = $_REQUEST['AdvisorID'];
        break;
        default: 
        ("Location: AdvisorsEdit.php");
    }

    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i A");             // Format: March 10, 2001, 5:16 PM

/*  Date Format Samples...
      $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");           // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
      $today = date("m.d.y");               // 03.10.01
      $today = date("j, n, Y");             // 10, 3, 2001
      $today = date("Ymd");                 // 20010310
      $today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');       // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
      $today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');     // it is the 10th day.
      $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");         // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
      $today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');       // 17:03:18 m is month
      $today = date("H:i:s");               // 17:16:18
*/

    $Salutation = $_REQUEST['txtSalutation'];
    $FirstName = $_REQUEST['txtFirstName'];
    $LastName = $_REQUEST['txtLastName'];



//  Validate the notation of meeting attendance
    if (isset($_REQUEST['rdomeeting'])) {
        $meetingID = $_REQUEST['rdomeeting'];
        if ($meetingID == 1) {
            echo "$meetingID";
        } elseif ($meetingID == 2) {
            echo "$meetingID";
        } elseif ($meetingID == 3) {
            echo "$meetingID";
        }

    } else {
        // Meeting Not Set
        $meetingID = NULL;
        echo "Meeting Designation Not Set!<br />";
    }


    if (!empty($_REQUEST['chkCon'])) {
        $ChkCon = $_REQUEST['chkCon'];
    } else {
        $ChkCon = 0; 
    }




    $Address1 = $_REQUEST['txtAddress1'];
    $Address2 = $_REQUEST['txtAddress2'];
    $City = $_REQUEST['txtCity'];
    $State = $_REQUEST['txtState'];
    $Zip = $_REQUEST['txtZipCode'];
    $Company = $_REQUEST['txtCompanyName'];
    $Title = $_REQUEST['txtTitle'];
    $Department = $_REQUEST['txtDepartment'];
    $HomeNo = $_REQUEST['txtPhone'];
    $CellNo = $_REQUEST['txtmobile'];
    $FaxNo =  $_REQUEST['txtFax'];
    $Email =  $_REQUEST['txtEMail'];
    $Major = $_REQUEST['selMajor'];
    $Notes = $_REQUEST['txtAreaNotes'];
?>
<table width="580" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="3" bordercolor="#006600">
<tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo "Date Added:$today" ;?></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo "Advisor ID:" ." ". "$AdvisorID" ;?></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="1%" >Name</td>
      <td><?php echo "$Salutation" ." ". "$FirstName" ." ". "$LastName" ; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Street Address</td>
      <td><?php echo "$Address1"; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Address 2</td>
      <td><?php echo "$Address2"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City, ST &amp; Zip</td>
      <td><?php echo "$City" .",". "$State" ."  ". "$Zip" ; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>    
    <td>Company Name</td>
    <td><?php echo "$Company"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Job Title</td>
      <td><?php echo "$Title"; ?> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>    
    <td>Department</td>
    <td><?php echo "$Department"; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Home Phone</td>
            <td><?php echo "$HomeNo"; ?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Cell Phone</td>
            <td><?php echo "$CellNo"; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>Fax</td>
           <td><?php echo "$FaxNo"; ?></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>EMail</td>
      <td><?php echo "$Email"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Major</td>
      <td><?php echo "$Major"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Will Attend Meeting</td>
      <td><?php echo "$meetingID"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Advisor Constituency</font></td>
      <td><?php echo "$ChkCon"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Notes</td>
      <td ><?php echo "$Notes"; ?></td>
    </tr>


</table>



<div id="outer">
    <div class="clear" id="header">
        <?php
        include "header.php";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <?php
        include "topmenu.php";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="primaryContentContainer">
            <div id="primaryContent">
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['menukey']))
                {
                $menukey = $_GET['menukey'];
                } 
                else 
                {
                $menukey = 0;
                }
            switch ($menukey) {
            case 1:
                    include "primarycontent.php";
                    break;
            case 2:
                    include "aboutme.php";
                    break;
            case 3:
                    include "WhatIDo.php";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    include "ContactMe.php";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    include "AdvisorsEdit.php"; 
                    break;

                case 10:
                    include "AdvisorsEditPost.php"
                    break;
        default:    // case else
                    include "primarycontent.php";
                    break; 

            }

?>
```

Comment: In switch case of $_POST['action'] default case is incorrect, should be `header("location: file.php");

Comment: Tried that, it works but does not carry over the data as I need it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was .. part one in the advisoredit.php part of the script.
The form action should be set to

```
  <form action="Index.php?menukey=10" method="post" name="AdvisorsEditPost">
```

but also had to change the following.

```
switch($_POST['action']) { 
case "Cancel": 
    header("Location: Index.php");
    break; 
case "Save": 
    $AdvisorID = $_REQUEST['AdvisorID'];
    break;
default: header("Location: Index.php");
}
```